# Mocking a DAO that returns a list throws NPE

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, junit, mockito

The DAO is simply:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public List<TestModel> findAll() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("TestModel.findAll").getResultList();
}
```

and the test is:

```
@Mock
private EntityManager em;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private TestModelDao dao = new TestModelDaoImpl();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(dao);
}
```

and the mock test is:

```
@Test
public void testFindAll() {
   when(dao.findAll()).thenReturn(testModelList());

   List<TestModel> testModels = dao.findAll();
   assertThat(testModels, is(testModelList()));
}
```

but the above test throws a `NullPointerException`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and the NPE is at what line, and what is null, and why?

Comment: You're not mocking the DAO. You're mocking the EntityManager. And your test makes no sense: you're testing Mockito, not your code.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito returns null when the method createNamedQuery is called so you get a NullpointerException on getResultList.

You have to

```
TypedQuery mockedQuery = mock(TypedQuery.class);

when(em.createNamedQuery(eq("TestModel.findAll")).thenReturn(mockedQuery);

when(mockedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(testModelList());
```

But like JB Nizet said you are testing the EntityManager which was already tested by the jpa provider.

I recommend you to create an Integration Test with dbunit and an in-memory database for testing your dao.